# Getting error using browse option in ckeditor in codeigniter php

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

To display browse option for uploading images added one extra plugin in ckeditor ["imagebrowser"](https://github.com/spantaleev/ckeditor-imagebrowser#usage). Clicking on browse server option getting an error as:

```
HTTP Status: 404/Not Found: "/path/to/images_list.json"
```

Followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/spantaleev/ckeditor-imagebrowser#usage) to implement browser option getting error.

In config.js file added this code to enable the plugin.

```
config.extraPlugins = "imagebrowser";
config.imageBrowser_listUrl = "/path/to/images_list.json";
```

images_list.json:

```
{
{
    "image": "/image1_200x150.jpg",
    "thumb": "/image1_thumb.jpg",
    "folder": "Small"
},
{
    "image": "/image2_200x150.jpg",
    "thumb": "/image2_thumb.jpg",
    "folder": "Small"
},

{
    "image": "/image1_full.jpg",
    "thumb": "/image1_thumb.jpg",
    "folder": "Large"
},
{
    "image": "/image2_full.jpg",
    "thumb": "/image2_thumb.jpg",
    "folder": "Large"
}
}
```

Created this file(images_list.json) in admin/ckeditor/plugins/imagebrowser/images_list.json

Comment: You need to change your json path here `/path/to/images_list.json`

Comment: @B.Desai But not getting the json file where they have added.

Comment: You have to create it for your images. Its not provided by plugin. see in doc **The imageBrowser_listUrl configuration parameter points to a URL that lists the server's images in a JSON format. Make sure to use an absolute path.**

Comment: @B.Desai can you give me an idea how to do that

Comment: @B.Desai it is asking for a JSON file i changed the path getting error as invalid JSON file

Comment: Then create valid json file

Comment: @B.Desai edited my code with json file how i created can you please check it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue by adding kcfinder inside your project folder.

Ex: htdocs/project/kcfinder

We can download it from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/kcfinder/files/KCFinder/2.51/

To integrate kcfinder in ckeditor need to add these lines inside ckeditor/config.js

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
```

To give permission for uploading file need to change permission in kcfinder/config.php change these lines

```
$_CONFIG = array(
'disabled' => false,
'denyZipDownload' => false,
'denyUpdateCheck' => false,
'denyExtensionRename' => false,
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For adding array json use `[]` do your json file must be as below :

```
[
{
    "image": "/image1_200x150.jpg",
    "thumb": "/image1_thumb.jpg",
    "folder": "Small"
},
{
    "image": "/image2_200x150.jpg",
    "thumb": "/image2_thumb.jpg",
    "folder": "Small"
},

{
    "image": "/image1_full.jpg",
    "thumb": "/image1_thumb.jpg",
    "folder": "Large"
},
{
    "image": "/image2_full.jpg",
    "thumb": "/image2_thumb.jpg",
    "folder": "Large"
}
]
```

change outer `{}` to `[]`

Comment: config.extraPlugins = "imagebrowser";
config.imageBrowser_listUrl = "admin/ckeditor/plugins/imagebrowser/images_list.json";

Comment: is this correct for enabling plugin and displaying the images

Comment: HTTP Status: 404/Not Found: "admin/ckeditor/plugins/imagebrowser/images_list.json" got this error

Comment: In URL it is displaying like this http://www.dev2.website.com/admin/ckeditor/plugins/imagebrowser/browser/browser.html?listUrl=admin%2Fckeditor%2Fplugins%2Fimagebrowser%2Fimages_list.json&CKEditor=description&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en